# Is it possible to get the WidgetInfo id for the widget that is currently providing a timeline?

Tags: ios, swift, widgetkit

`WidgetCenter.shared.getCurrentConfigurations()` returns a list of `WidgetInfo` structs (one for each widget the user has set up), each of which includes an `id` parameter which the [documentation says](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/widgetinfo/id) is "the stable identity of the widget".

Is there any way to get that same stable `id` for a widget *while it is providing its timeline*? In other words, I want to access the current widget's `WidgetInfo` struct while we are constructing a timeline for that widget in the `getTimeline(for...)` implementation of IntentTimelineProvider.

Comment: I was wondering the same, ever found a solution?

Comment: @Apoleo Sadly no.

Comment: I have confirmed with an Apple engineer that this use case is not supported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I confirmed with an Apple engineer in June 2023 that this use case is not supported.